# Adding resources into netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, embedded-resource

I would like to know how to add files to my NetBeans project and then access them via getResource or getResourceAsStream. But apparently I can't figure out where my problem lies.

I added some xml file into the root folder of the project and when I try to access it via

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("some_file.xsd");
```

I get `null` as a result.

Comment: What packages/directories are shown under the 'root' in Netbeans?  AFAIR resources in various directories are included in the built Jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the `some_file.xsd` is present in the **classpath**, then also verify if the path to the file is proper.

If not you can instead just read it using `FileInputStream`. Something like this:-

```
InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
```

and make sure that `filePath` is a proper relative URL.